# drop down comboBox if else statement error

Tags: c#

If I write in `cmbGrNo.text` then there will be an

> Input string is not in correct format

How can I identify that which combobox is edit?
I write in combobox and then click on search button the compiler is giving me error cause it does not accept the other combobox text. It only accepts the value of first one ...
**please help me**

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbAdmissionNo.Text.Length == 0 && cmbRollNo.Text.Length == 0 && cmbStudentName.Text.Length == 0 && cmbGRNo.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Student Name OR Admission No OR Gr No OR Roll No"," INSERT FIELDS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        if (StudentDBClass.CheckStudent(cmbStudentName.Text))
        {
            DataTable dt = StudentDBClass.getTableBYStdName(cmbStudentName.Text);
            txtAdminNo.Text = "Admission No : " + dt.Rows[0]["AddmissionNo"];
            txtGrNo.Text = "GR No : " + dt.Rows[0]["GRNo"];
            txtClass.Text = "Class : " + dt.Rows[0]["ClassName"];
            txtStudentName.Text = "Student Name : " + dt.Rows[0]["StudentName"];
            txtFatherName.Text = "Father Name : " + dt.Rows[0]["FatherName"];
            txtRollNo.Text = "Roll No: " + dt.Rows[0]["RollNo"];
            dgvStdFeeCollection.DataSource = null;
            dgvStdFeeCollection.DataSource = StudentFeeCollectionDBClass.getStdNameForDgvFeeCollection(cmbStudentName.Text);
            cmbAdmissionNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbGRNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbRollNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbAdmissionNo.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbGRNo.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbRollNo.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (StudentDBClass.CheckWithAdmissionNo(Convert.ToInt32(cmbAdmissionNo.Text)))
        {
            DataTable dt = StudentDBClass.getTableBYAddmissionNo(Convert.ToInt32(cmbAdmissionNo.Text));
            txtAdminNo.Text = "Admission No : " + dt.Rows[0]["AddmissionNo"];
            txtGrNo.Text = "GR No : " + dt.Rows[0]["GRNo"];
            txtClass.Text = "Class : " + dt.Rows[0]["ClassName"];
            txtStudentName.Text = "Student Name : " + dt.Rows[0]["StudentName"];
            txtFatherName.Text = "Father Name : " + dt.Rows[0]["FatherName"];
            txtRollNo.Text = "Roll No: " + dt.Rows[0]["RollNo"];
            dgvStdFeeCollection.DataSource = null;
            dgvStdFeeCollection.DataSource = StudentFeeCollectionDBClass.getAdmissionNoForDgvFeeCollection(Convert.ToInt32(cmbAdmissionNo.Text));
            cmbStudentName.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbGRNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbRollNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbGRNo.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbStudentName.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbRollNo.Text = string.Empty;

        }
        else if (StudentDBClass.CheckGRNo(Convert.ToInt32(cmbGRNo.Text)))
        {
            DataTable dt = StudentDBClass.getTableGrNo(Convert.ToInt32(cmbGRNo.Text));
            txtAdminNo.Text = "Admission No : " + dt.Rows[0]["AddmissionNo"];
            txtGrNo.Text = "GR No : " + dt.Rows[0]["GRNo"];
            txtClass.Text = "Class : " + dt.Rows[0]["ClassName"];
            txtStudentName.Text = "Student Name : " + dt.Rows[0]["StudentName"];
            txtFatherName.Text = "Father Name : " + dt.Rows[0]["FatherName"];
            txtRollNo.Text = "Roll No: " + dt.Rows[0]["RollNo"];
            dgvStdFeeCollection.DataSource = null;
            dgvStdFeeCollection.DataSource = StudentFeeCollectionDBClass.getGrNoForDgvFeeCollection(Convert.ToInt32(cmbGRNo.Text));
            cmbAdmissionNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbStudentName.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbRollNo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cmbAdmissionNo.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbStudentName.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbRollNo.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: something to do with the combo box's selected.value or selected index.

Comment: what is the value of `cmbGrNo.Text` when you debug through this?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the `Convert.ToInt32` receives a string that its not able to parse.

You are selecting the text value of the combobox, this will not return an integer.

You need to select the `SelectedValue` of the combobox.

Something like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(cmbGrNo.SelectedValue.Text)
```

Comment: cmbGrNo.SelectedValue.ToString() is appeared not text and this is also not working with my conditions @paqogomez

Comment: @DaniDanish what is the value of `cmbGrNo.SelectedValue.ToString()`?

Comment: its int value i am using Convert.ToInt32(cmbGrNo.text)

Comment: in every if else condition @paqgomez

Comment: You misunderstand me.  I want to know its value.  Is it 35, or `Q22` or what?  What is the VALUE?

Comment: If you run `Convert.ToInt32("38");` it will not fail.  So there is another character in there.  Have you tried to `Trim()` the string? Could a space be messing things up?

Comment: @DaniDanish, I forgot to add your name, so it didnt post the previous message to you